# Can 50% CPU usage indicate bottlenecking on a hyperthreaded CPU?

Tags: cpu, performance, hyper-threading

I'm trying to increase my FPS in a videogame and as such I'm trying to find the bottleneck in my system. Nothing seems to run at 100%, even when the FPS limit is much higher than the actual FPS (I'm getting up to max 80 FPS while the limit is 240 for testing purposes).

But then it occurred to me; I have a hyper-threaded CPU, with twice as many 'virtual' cores as 'real' cores. Perhaps the cores aren't showing 100% use because if hyper-threading is being properly used no 'virtual' core should ever actually run at 100%.

Is my understanding correct that when my cores are running at an average of 50%, that means the CPU is actually running as fast as it can?

Comment: Virtual cores almost never run at full tilt, practically, even on properly expensive processing like app compile or video compression. Real cores do the heavy lifting, virtual ones get the spare time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though the number of physical cores is not given, the principle should apply to all number of cores/virtual processors.

For example, if the application does create two threads with full load, 100% CPU load will occur on a machine with one core (1 virtual cpu) and on a machine with one core with hyper-threading (2 virtual CPUs).
Adding a second core keeps the load at 100% (2 virtual CPUs), adding a second core with hyper-threading now reduces this load to 50% (4 virtual CPUs), i.e. it seems like the application is not able to distribute its workload to more processors and therefore one can either see the software as the bottleneck or the single-threading performance of the CPU.

In general, a physical processor with hyper-threading and therefore two virtual processors is not as fast as two single physical processors, but if your application is capable of distributing its workload, if will benefit from it, at least the CPU graph will reflect that, real-world performance depends on the instructions.

You probably cannot change the videogame, but if you don't have a low-end CPU you probably may also not benefit much from replacing it, because the single-threading-performance did not improve much over the last years.

Answer (score -1):

Have seen behavior like this with old software that wasn't multi processor aware. In those cases you may see a constant 50% cpu load. The hardware isn't the limiting factor in those cases. Looking at your question you are talking about a videogame. For video you would want to have the sofware use GPU rather than CPU.